# iOS: Optimizing UIViewController and/or MKMapKit MKPolyline with GCD?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, mkpolyline

I'm making an app that uses the use of coordinate data. My app would launch, and the other will have to go through a view different view controllers before getting to this stage. The user will select a coordinate route before entering this particular `UIViewController`.

I currently, for the sake of testing purposes have all this being done in `viewDidLoad`. The purpose of this view controller is to display a map with a `MKPolyline` based on a route that is predetermined. The `MKPolyline` will be a gradient based on a factor, in this case, `velocity`.

`GradientPolylineOverlay` is from https://github.com/wdanxna/GradientPolyline, and [Gradient Polyline with MapKit ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682688/gradient-polyline-with-mapkit-ios).

My main issue is that, with my code as is, the rendering of the `MKPolyline` is very slow, and any events on the `mapView` are slow and laggy.

I have determined since I have many coordinates (this can easily be over 7000) that one of the two following lines are causing the issue:

`[mapView addOverlay:polyline];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    data = delegate.data; // contains sorted/parse data from my source
    NSInteger pointsCount = [data sampleCount];

    // set up mapView
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    mapView.delegate = self;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(*[data getGPSCoordinatesForSample:0], 500, 500);
    [mapView setRegion:region];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D pointsToUse[pointsCount];

    float* velocity =0;
    velocity = malloc(sizeof(float)*pointsCount);

    // pointCount contains 7000 coordinates!
    for(int i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++) {
            CGPoint p = CGPointMake([data getGPSCoordinatesForSample:i]->latitude,[data getGPSCoordinatesForSample:i]->longitude);
            pointsToUse[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(p.x,p.y);
            velocity[i] =[data getGPSVelocityForSample:i];
    }


    polyline = [[GradientPolylineOverlay alloc] initWithPoints:pointsToUse velocity:velocity count:pointsCount];

    // issues!
    [mapView addOverlay:polyline];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    free(velocity);
}
```

I am lead to believe that it this point, to boost the performance, I should use Grand Central Dispatch. Using GCD, I altered my code to:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("Test", 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D pointsToUse[pointsCount];


    float* velocity =0;
    velocity = malloc(sizeof(float)*pointsCount);

    // pointCount contains 7000 coordinates!
    for(int i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++) {
        CGPoint p = CGPointMake([data getGPSCoordinatesForSample:i]->latitude,[data getGPSCoordinatesForSample:i]->longitude);
        pointsToUse[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(p.x,p.y);
        velocity[i] =[data getGPSVelocityForSample:i];
    }


    polyline = [[GradientPolylineOverlay alloc] initWithPoints:pointsToUse velocity:velocity count:j];
    [mapView addOverlay:polyline]; // Crash
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    });
});
```

`[mapView addOverlay:polyline];` gives off a `Thread 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS` debug error.

My ideal solution would have to use all the coordinates, but I can scale this down if required. If I can use GCD at some place in the code, where would the best place be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think `mapView:rendererForOverlay` or `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap` is a good option.

They are both in MKMapViewDelegate.

[This is the document.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1)