# Turn NSGradient into NSColor in Swift

Tags: swiftui, gradient, mkpolyline, nscolor, nsgradient

I am trying to make an MKPolyline for a SwiftUI map where it shows a persons location for a day and I want a gradient changing from blue to green from the first point in their location to the last point in blue. I have this code

```
renderer.strokeColor = NSGradient(colors: [NSColor.blue, NSColor.green])
```

I have also tried

```
renderer.strokeColor = NSColor(NSGradient(colors: [NSColor.blue, NSColor.green]))
```

and

```
renderer.strokeColor = NSColor(Color(Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.green])))
```

but these all return errors about turning Gradients into colors. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot convert `NSColor` to `NSGradient` and vice versa. The type of `strokeColor` is `NSColor`.  It's not a flexible SwiftUI `ShapeStyle`. To draw a gradient see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682688/gradient-polyline-with-mapkit-ios

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @vadian I did this

```
if let routePolyline = overlay as? MKPolyline {
  let renderer = MKGradientPolylineRenderer(polyline: routePolyline)
    renderer.setColors([NSColor.blue, NSColor.green], locations: [])
  renderer.lineWidth = 2
  return renderer
}
```